# Tally XML Get GST Rate Setup by Stock Group

Tags: tally, tdl

I am able to get the GST rates grouped by Stock Group using the below XML, but How do i pass the stock group in this request so that i can get GST Rates for items under the particular stock group

```
<ENVELOPE>
<HEADER>
    <VERSION>1</VERSION>
    <TALLYREQUEST>EXPORT</TALLYREQUEST>
    <TYPE>Data</TYPE>
    <ID>GST Rate Setup</ID>
</HEADER>
<BODY>
    <DESC>
        <STATICVARIABLES>
            <SVEXPORTFORMAT>$$SysName:XML</SVEXPORTFORMAT>
            
        </STATICVARIABLES>
        <FETCHLIST>
            <FETCH>*</FETCH>    
        </FETCHLIST>
    </DESC>
</BODY>
</ENVELOPE>
```

I tried to pass the stock group name using static variables, but since i don't know the variable name, i am getting nowhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can create Custom reports by extending existing reports in TDL definition

In below xml I extended **GST Rate Setup** by mentioning in **use** Tag

To known the variable used in report we need to refer TDL code which is available in [TDL Developer Application](https://tallysolutions.com/download/)[image: Source Code Screenshot]

Here we are overwriting **Stock Group Name** by setting **testgroup**

Replace **testgroup** with whatever group youwant

```
<ENVELOPE>
<HEADER>
    <VERSION>1</VERSION>
    <TALLYREQUEST>EXPORT</TALLYREQUEST>
    <TYPE>Data</TYPE>
    <ID>Cust GST Rate Setup</ID>
</HEADER>
<BODY>
    <DESC>
        <STATICVARIABLES>
            <SVEXPORTFORMAT>$$SysName:XML</SVEXPORTFORMAT>
            <SVShowAll>No</SVShowAll >
        </STATICVARIABLES>
        <TDL>
            <TDLMESSAGE>
                <Report ISMODIFY="No" ISFIXED="No" ISINITIALIZE="No" ISOPTION="No" ISINTERNAL="No" NAME="Cust GST Rate Setup">
                    <Use>GST Rate Setup</Use>
                    <Set>Stock Group Name:testgroup</Set>
                    <Form>GST Rate Setup</Form>
                </Report>
            </TDLMESSAGE>
        </TDL>
    </DESC>
</BODY>
</ENVELOPE>
```